# `mysql_upgrade` is failing with no real reason given

Tags: mysql, mysql5.5

I'm upgrading from MySQL 5.1 to 5.5, running `mysql_upgrade` and getting this output:

```
# mysql_upgrade
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

Any ideas on where to look for what's happening (or, not happening?) so I can fix whatever is wrong and actually run `mysql_upgrade`?

Thanks!

More output:

```
# mysql_upgrade --verbose
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed

# mysql_upgrade --debug-check --debug-info
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed

# mysql_upgrade --debug-info
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed

User time 0.00, System time 0.00
Maximum resident set size 1260, Integral resident set size 0
Non-physical pagefaults 447, Physical pagefaults 0, Swaps 0
Blocks in 0 out 16, Messages in 0 out 0, Signals 0
Voluntary context switches 9, Involuntary context switches 5

# mysql_upgrade --debug-check
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

After shutting down `mysqld --skip-grant-tables` via `mysqladmin shutdown` and restarting mysql via `service mysql start`, the error log loops through this set of errors over and over:

```
130730 21:03:27 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
130730 21:03:27 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
130730 21:03:27 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130730 21:03:27 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
130730 21:03:27 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
130730 21:03:27 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 20.0G
130730 21:03:29 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130730 21:03:30 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 588190222435
130730 21:03:30  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 588192055067
130730 21:03:30  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 81298895, file name /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.006008
130730 21:03:33  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130730 21:03:34 InnoDB: 5.5.32 started; log sequence number 588192055067
130730 21:03:34 [Note] Recovering after a crash using /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin
130730 21:03:34 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
130730 21:03:34 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
130730 21:03:34 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
130730 21:03:34 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
130730 21:03:34 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
130730 21:03:34 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist
```

MySQL log during start up via `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`

```
130730 21:19:36 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
130730 21:19:36 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130730 21:19:36 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130730 21:19:36 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
130730 21:19:36 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
130730 21:19:37 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 20.0G
130730 21:19:39 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130730 21:19:39 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
130730 21:19:42  InnoDB: Warning: allocated tablespace 566, old maximum was 0
130730 21:19:42  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130730 21:19:43 InnoDB: 5.5.32 started; log sequence number 588192055067
130730 21:19:43 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
130730 21:19:43 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
130730 21:19:43 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
130730 21:19:43 [Warning] Can't open and lock time zone table: Table 'mysql.time_zone_leap_second' doesn't exist trying to live without them
130730 21:19:43 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
130730 21:19:43 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_current' has the wrong structure
130730 21:19:43 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_history' has the wrong structure
130730 21:19:43 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_history_long' has the wrong structure
130730 21:19:43 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_consumers' has the wrong structure
130730 21:19:43 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_instruments' has the wrong structure
130730 21:19:43 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_timers' has the wrong structure
130730 21:19:43 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'performance_timers' has the wrong structure
130730 21:19:43 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'threads' has the wrong structure
130730 21:19:43 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_by_thread_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
130730 21:19:43 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_by_instance' has the wrong structure
130730 21:19:43 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_global_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
130730 21:19:43 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_summary_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
130730 21:19:43 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_summary_by_instance' has the wrong structure
130730 21:19:43 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'mutex_instances' has the wrong structure
130730 21:19:43 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'rwlock_instances' has the wrong structure
130730 21:19:43 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'cond_instances' has the wrong structure
130730 21:19:43 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'file_instances' has the wrong structure
130730 21:19:43 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1-log'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
```

As I understand it, all the table structure/existence issues (as it relates to mysql system tables) should be corrected by running `mysql_upgrade` :

Comment: Also probably worth nothing, `mysqld` is running, with `--skip-grant-tables` option. I can connect via `mysql` on the terminal with no credentials, and I get no errors via syslog or anywhere else I can think to look when I run `mysql_upgrade`

Comment: The [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html) covers upgrading to 5.5 from 5.1 pretty well. If you have followed all the instructions here, it would be worth mentioning. If you have not, well...

Comment: If your mysql root user doesn't have a password, don't include ` -p` in ` mysql_upgrade -u root -p`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is incredibly generic, and I apologize for that.

I couldn't find a direct cause and solution to the problem I was having, so I resorted to re-installing MySQL to see if that would work. Turns out, re-installing did the trick. That was a lame way to fix it, but it was the only option I had left.

A lot of the other answers on this question are problems I had to work through to get mysql_upgrade to run initially, but for whatever reason - it failed as it was trying to run some automated queries, and I couldn't find the documentation on which queries it was running so I could fix them.

Comment: Yeah once that data dir of mysql has been corrupted there is pretty much nothing you can do

Answer (score 97):

I think that it needs username and password

```
mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```

If I don't pass them I get your error

**Edit**: thanks to the comments now I know that there are other reasons, maybe less frequent but it's best to be aware of them too

So you get that error when

- you didn't pass username and password
- you passed your credentials, but they were wrong
- the MySQL server isn't running
- the permissions' tables are ruined (then you must restart MySQL with `mysqld --skip-grant-table`)
- the table mysql.plugin is missing (you'll see an error about that when starting MySQL which suggests to run... mysql_upgrade, and that fails. You probably have some obsolete configuration in my.cnf)

Comment: This was exactly the problem I had - why the hell couldn't it just say "Could not authenticate" or "Connection error" or something? So angry ...

Comment: Guys, you get the same error if your password is wrong too. so be informed.

Comment: And you get the same error if the server isn't running, even though it appears to accept the password.

Comment: just when the database table or the database format is broken too, it doesn't work either, then you need to start the daemon with
"mysqld --skip-grant-tables" and run mysql_upgrade in another terminal!

Comment: +1 for this. Yet another reason I hate MySQL

Comment: Thanks! You are a genius! 

What an idiot failed to output something like 'Authentication error'?

Comment: `Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist`

Answer (score 10):

I just encountered these precise symptoms when upgrading from 5.5 to 5.6, and it turned out to be a service reachability issue.

Even though the cli MySQL client could connect to my local DB instance with only a -u and -p provided, I also needed to specify -h 127.0.0.1 for mysql_upgrade as it was attempting a socket file connection and failing miserably in the attempt.

Comment: that was exactly my problem because I run mysqd like this:
mysqld --skip-grant-tables --user=mysql

Answer (score 9):

That seems a Plesk server, when using Plesk there is no root for Mysql, but the administrator of Mysql called admin, so this command should work on Plesk as I tried it before:

```
mysql_upgrade -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow`
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 5):

you could try running these one by one to see where it fails:

> mysql_upgrade executes the following commands to check and repair tables and to upgrade the system tables:

```
mysqlcheck --all-databases --check-upgrade --auto-repair  
mysql < fix_priv_tables  
mysqlcheck --all-databases --check-upgrade --fix-db-names --fix-table-names
```

from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-upgrade.html

Comment: Thought about that, but `fix_priv_tables` is a script that is generated by `mysql_upgrade` in order to fixup the privelege tables

Comment: good point, maybe try just the first mysqlcheck line?  And try running from the bin folder directly, fwiw, `/usr/bin/mysql_upgrade`

Answer (score 5):

Same issue! The solution for me came from http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/query-pr.cgi?pr=180624

Briefly: the error is misleading! run `mysql_upgrade -u root -p` with the DB on-line and provide the root password.

Answer (score 3):

Our DBA uninstalled mysql version 5.0.95 instead of just upgrading to 5.5.39.  The uninstall backed up the `/etc/my.cnf` to `/etc/my.cnf.rpmsave` then removed it, and this prevented MySQL from starting up properly:

```
140902 15:00:57 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140902 15:00:57 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140902 15:00:57 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140902 15:00:57 [ERROR] Aborting
```

You can do any of the following:

- Compare the my.cnf files manually and bring over appropriate config settings for InnoDB
- Restore the `my.cnf.rpmsave` back over the original (check first for any new default settings you should add!)
- Use a diff tool like `vimdiff` to compare the `my.cnf.rpmsave` to the new `my.cnf` and brought back over the tweaks that had been made to MySQL config, including the InnoDB settings.

  `[root]# vimdiff /etc/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf.rpmsave`

I did the last option, then was able to start MySQL:

```
root]# service mysqld start
Starting mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]
```

and now the `mysql_upgrade` works fine, using `mysql_upgrade -uroot -p` so it prompted me for root password.

```
[root]# mysql_upgrade -uroot -p
Enter password:
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
Running 'mysqlcheck with default connection arguments
....
```

Hope this helps!

and also using `mysql_upgrade -uroot -p` failed because it needs MySQL to be running!

Lessons learned:

- Backup my.cnf before upgrade... And actually do an in-place upgrade instead of uninstall then install of the newer version.
- Get MySQL running so you can use mysql_upgrade.
- Profit.

Answer (score 2):

You must check the permission all files under mysql data. It should be the same owner of mysql PID (mysql or _mysql). This sometime happens because restore data from file without proper permission. For example if your mysql data is under /var/lib/mysql

```
chown -R mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

Same problem for me, but the source of my problems was the old password format. While mysql can be forced to connect using the old format with "skip-secure-auth", mysql_upgrade has not this option. You need first to update the root password with the new format and then you can upgrade your mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem upgrading from 5.1 to 5.5.

This worked for me:
`sudo mysql_upgrade -S <path-to-socket> -u <myuser> -p<mypass>`

My error was probably caused by permissions to the socket path, but haven't the time to verify it was the cause.

Comment: I'd moved my DataDir at some time, I guess that's why I needed the path to the socket

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this as well after upgrading my system from Mint 12 to Mint 15.  I had archived /var/lib/mysql and put it back in place post-upgrade.  I ran the first `mysqlcheck` from user16081's comment, and it complained about mysql.sock.

I started mysqld using `/usr/sbin/mysqld &` and `mysql_upgrade` ran fine.

Comment: That's a pretty scary method for upgrading MySQL, but I am glad it worked for you.

Comment: @aaron-copley: actually it didn't completely work.  MySQL 5.5.32 is partially ignoring many of my InnoDB tables; they appear in `SHOW TABLES`, but otherwise don't exist.  I'm currently trying to get mysql-utilities to work, but that's complaining about missing python modules.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across the same problem.
I solved it by including the -S /path/to/mysql.sock

In my particular case the output of mysql_upgrade was:
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed

That's pretty useless. --verbose made no difference.

Plugging around I settled on the following command and it worked like a charm:
mysql_upgrade -S /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock -uUSERNAME -p

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem, and I found out that,

1. it required MySQL Service to be running
2. it required username and password

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue.

I solved this by installing new database by `mysql_install_db --user=mysql` as described in the comments of  my `rc.mysql` file in /etc.

Then I was able to start mysql daemon and use 'mysql' or whatever you want connected with mysql package.

I had this problem on slackware arm , but suppose it doesn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a few versions of mysqld running locally that made mysql_upgrade fail with *Error: Failed while fetching Server version! Could be due to unauthorized access.* 
`ps aux | grep mysql` and make sure mysqld is all shut down. Then brew uninstall all version, reinstall the right version. And after that mysql_upgrade started to work.

Answer (score 0):

always check the log /var/log/mysqld.log first, most of the time answers are there

Answer (score -1):

try

```
mysql_upgrade --verbose
```

or maybe even (or both)

```
--debug-check --debug-info
```

Comment: Tried those, no real useful information, I don't think |;

Comment: restarted and pasted some error log info \; not sure why it would keep looping through those same errors over and over.

Comment: seems like you have an error there -- `130730 21:03:34 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist` I think that's what causing whole thing to fail.

Comment: but before that, try mysql_upgrade --version and provide output for that.

Comment: `mysql_upgrade --version` produces no version output (just the FATAL ERROR error). `mysql --version` is mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.32, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2, and mysqld version is 5.5

Comment: also, as I understand it; `mysql.host` should be created by `mysql_upgrade` \:

Comment: temporary disable selinux, try same operation again. i'd probably consider reinstalling mysql, also try myisamchk to run against mysql db.

Answer (score -3):

The root user for MySQL is named "admin", not root. The right command is

```
mysql_upgrade -uadmin -p
```

Comment: This is absolutely wrong. The root user in MySQL is `root`.